# How to fix "Native linking failed..." errors when installing Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.MLKit in Xamarin.Ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, firebase-mlkit

I have created a new Xamarin Forms (v3.6) project and installed the Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.MLKit nuget.

After compiling the project, I get lots of errors like this:

> Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: GTLRVision_DetectedBreak. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLRVision_DetectedBreak' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application
>
> Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: GTMLogMininumLevelFilter. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogMininumLevelFilter' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application
>
> Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: FIRApp. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application
>
> Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPBRootObject. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in
>
> Native linking failed. Please review the build log and the user flags provided to gcc: -ObjC -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz -ObjC -ObjC -ObjC -ObjC -ObjC -ObjC -ObjC -lc++ -ObjC -lc++ -ObjC -lc++ -ObjC -lc++

Until now, I tried the following:

- Delete bin/obj folders, clean and recompile the project
- Re-install the nuget
- Update xCode to the latest version
- Change linking behaviors in the iOS project.
- Added "--registrar:static" inside the Additional mtouch arguments inside de iOS Build configuration.

None of them worked.

Is there any solution out there?

Comment: Have a look at this [thread](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/247) may help.

Comment: It worked for me! Apparently, I was missing the Firebase initialization. Thank you!

Comment: Will you accept it if I post an answer? We can help more people with same problem.

Comment: Sure, no problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have initialized Firebase after you installed `Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.MLKit` in `Xamarin.iOS`.

Here is the code of initialization:

```
Firebase.Core.App.Configure ();
```

Refer: [GoogleApisForiOSComponents](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/247)